# Xamarin/Android resources-file has refs to Xamarin.Auth

Tags: xamarin.forms

Hmmm I bit confusing problem, hard to explain, but here goes.

I have a Xamarin Forms (.Net Standard 2.0)-project that happens to use "Xamarin.Auth"-NuGet package to do facebook-login, so thats why Im using Xamarin.Auth... Now to my problem.

This all started with that I VS didnt seem to find Resources.Id.toolbar. I looked in the resources-file and see what I only can interpret as a bug in the generation of the resources-file. There are a lot of references/definitions to Xamarin.Auth. I dont know what sense it would make to have for example

global::**Xamarin.Auth**.Resource.Animation.slide_out_left = global::MyProj.Droid.Resource.Animation.slide_out_left;

This is part of my Resources.designer.cs-file

```
public partial class Resource
{ 
    static Resource()
    {
        global::Android.Runtime.ResourceIdManager.UpdateIdValues();
    }

    public static void UpdateIdValues()
    {
        global::Xamarin.Auth.Resource.Animation.slide_in_right = global::MyProj.Droid.Resource.Animation.slide_in_right;
        global::Xamarin.Auth.Resource.Animation.slide_out_left = global::MyProj.Droid.Resource.Animation.slide_out_left;
        global::Xamarin.Auth.Resource.Attribute.font = global::MyProj.Droid.Resource.Attribute.font;
        global::Xamarin.Auth.Resource.Attribute.fontProviderAuthority = global::MyProj.Droid.Resource.Attribute.fontProviderAuthority;
        global::Xamarin.Auth.Resource.Attribute.fontProviderCerts = global::MyProj.Droid.Resource.Attribute.fontProviderCerts;
        global::Xamarin.Auth.Resource.Attribute.fontProviderFetchStrategy = global::MyProj.Droid.Resource.Attribute.fontProviderFetchStrategy;
```

...

Anyone knows if this would be related to that I cant find Resource.Ids.toolbar or how to not mix in Xamarin.Auth when creating the resource-file?

Comment: Have you checked your support libraries version for conflicts with your Xamarin.Auth package?

Comment: Sorry...thought I answered this ...but the answer dissapeared...anyway. Yes, no conflicts. I have converted my solution to a shared one instead. Too many problems with .net standard 2.0-solutions right now